# Transform an iterator to another iterator

Tags: javascript

In Javascript you can transform an iterator into another iterator (the `map()` function in most languages) like this:

```js
function* mapIterator(input, transformer) {
  for (const value of input) {
    yield transformer(value);
  }
}
```

For example to transform the values of a `Map` you can do this:

```js
function mapValues(input, transformer) {
  function* gen() {
    for (const [key, value] of input.entries()) {
      yield [key, transformer(value)];
    }
  }
  return new Map(gen());
}
```

However this is little slower than collecting everything into an array and just looping over the array. I would have thought there should be a native function that does this `map()` transformation but I can't seem to find it.

Does such a function exist?

Comment: do you have some data to illustrate the function?

Comment: It's just a `Map`. Something like `mapValues(new Map([[1, 2], [3, 4]], x => x*2);`.

Comment: where is the specific problem with the code?

Comment: @NinaScholz There is no *problem* with the code shown. OP is asking whether a native, built-in API exists for the task.